# How to overwrite the output file in GulpJS?

Tags: sass, gulp, less, overwrite, preprocessor

I'm using GulpJS to compile LESS and SASS files into only one file CSS. I successfully merged the files into one, however, when I edited any of the LESS/SASS file and compiled again, it didn't overwrite the style.css but continuously to duplicate the old elements. Is there a way to overwrite the output file if there's update on the less/sass?

Here is my code in gulp.js:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var merge = require('merge-stream');
var bower = require('bower');

gulp.task('default', function () {

    var lessStream = gulp.src('./src/style.less')
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(concat('style.less'));

    var scssStream = gulp.src('./src/style.sass')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(concat('style.sass'));

    var cssStream = gulp.src('assets/dist/style.css', {
            base: './'
        })
        .pipe(concat('style.css'));

    var mergedStream = merge(lessStream, scssStream, cssStream)
        .pipe(concat('style.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/dist/'));

    return mergedStream;
    gulp.start('bower');
});

gulp.task('bower', () => {
    return gulp.src('assets/dist/style.css')
        .pipe(wiredep())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/dist/'));
})
```

Comment: What version of  gulp-less?
Looks like it's known bug with 4.0
https://github.com/stevelacy/gulp-less/issues/283

Comment: Hi, I'm using version 4.0 of gulp-less but seems like there's no problem with the CSS reflection, it generated well. I just don't know which way to overwrite the output file...

Comment: Can you just try 3.5 version?

Comment: I suspect your problem is that you put `concat` *everywhere* (for instance instead of creating a new "style.css" you seems to concatenate the new CSS result to the already existing "style.css"). I.e. look through your script once more and decide if every `concat` there is actually making any sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is in this part

```
var cssStream = gulp.src('assets/dist/style.css', {
        base: './'
    })
    .pipe(concat('style.css'));

var mergedStream = merge(lessStream, scssStream, cssStream)
    .pipe(concat('style.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/dist/'));
```

You are grabbing the existing assets/dist/style.css, concatenating it with all the other files and then saving it in assets/dist/style.css. So next time you run the process, you'll grab style.css (with everything that it already has) and concatenate it with the other files.

I wouldn't grab style.css if all it has is the output from the less and sass files.